# How generate random border color position

Tags: css, angular

l am try to generator random border color for my cards as in image below .

[image: Example border styles]

In my code below he is give only on left side of card . How can i generator border one on left side and sec card on right side ?

```
 this.border =this.getRandomColor()
   getRandomColor()
    {
      return {
        borderLeft: '4px solid #' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)
    }
    
    }
```

html

```
<ion-card [ngStyle]="border">
  <ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-subtitle>Awesome Subtitle</ion-card-subtitle>
    <ion-card-title>Awesome Title</ion-card-title>
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content >
    Awesome content
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: Switch between `borderLeft` and `borderRight` based on index. If index is even vs if index is odd. This can be checked using the `%` (modulus) operator

Comment: Can you post full answer please ? l am beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Terry mentioned in the comment you can use a variable to track down the index. You based on the index change the side as below :

```
calls = 0;

get border() {
     const side = this.calls++ % 2 === 0 ? "Left" : "Right";
     const border = {}; 
     border[`border${side}`] = '4px solid #' + 
     Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)
     return border;
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jcq7gt?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: thank you for answering , l have error under `% === 0`

Comment: Should i  put `[ngStyle]="border()"` ?

Comment: @Maher no it's just a getter only property.

Comment: @Maher that was another typo  `boder` -> `border`

Answer (score 0):

just use the index of the loop rendering the multiple cards. And pass that index to the function defining the style.

so update your html with the following code:

```
<ion-card [ngStyle]="getRandomColor(index)">
  <ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-subtitle>Awesome Subtitle</ion-card-subtitle>
    <ion-card-title>Awesome Title</ion-card-title>
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content >
    Awesome content
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

And .ts with the following lines:

```
 getRandomColor(index)
    { 
      if(index%2 !==0){
      return {
        borderLeft: '4px solid #' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)}
    }
     else{
return{ borderRight: '4px solid #' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)}
    }
    
    }
```

Edited:
Please update your html with these lines.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items, let index=index">
<ion-card [ngStyle]="getRandomColor(index)">
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-subtitle>Awesome Subtitle</ion-card-subtitle>
        <ion-card-title>Awesome Title</ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content >
        Awesome content
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</div>
```

Comment: `[ngStyle]="getRandomColor(items?.length)"` ?

Comment: no you are doing wrong. you have to send the index. please show me what have you used for ngFor to iterate through items array.

Comment: You use the *ngFor="let item of items, let index = index"

Comment: Okay i did what you said . i have 2 items in array . and i have only one color

Comment: Hey just replace the if condition in the method by if((index+1)%2 !==0)

Comment: HEy we just missed adding return to the else condition. I have updated the answer.